# Selenium RemoteWebDriver 2.39 with firefox 26

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium-standalone-server-2.39 as RemoteWebDriver[server is running on different machine] with firefox 26 on windows 7.test execution is working fine but when code try to **close or quit the driver/browser** during suite teardown then it gives **UnreachableBrowserException.** although If I use webdriver locally[server is running on same machine] it works perfectly.

I have already **tried with different version of webdriver 2.36,2.37,2.38 with ff 26** but same exception comes every time.

If someone help me to resolve this problem it will be very helpful.

**what combination of selenium webdriver and firefox which works perfectly?**

EDIT: This simple piece of code i'm trying to run-

```
 public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception {
       URL url = new URL( "http", ip, 4444, "/wd/hub" );
       FirefoxProfile pf = new FirefoxProfile(new File("D:\\ffprofile"));
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities =DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
       capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, pf);
       System.out.println("1");
       capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
       System.out.println("2");
       WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url,capabilities);
      System.out.println("4");
      driver.get("http://www.google.com");
      driver.close();
    }
```

Exception:

```
    Jan 07, 2014 1:10:32 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
    INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
    Jan 07, 2014 1:10:32 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
    INFO: Retrying request
Jan 07, 2014 1:10:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jan 07, 2014 1:10:51 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Jan 07, 2014 1:11:10 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jan 07, 2014 1:11:10 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.38.0', revision: 'bd32d4e', time: '2013-12-05 16:15:38'
System info: host: 'symc-w7-12281', ip: '10.88.155.166', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:418)
    at SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: All combinations of browser and driver works fine.  The only time there are issues is if you are using the binary Chrome or IE drivers, and the version of your browser is too new for the binary driver to handle, and even then, bugs are not common.   You must be doing something unusual.  You should post more detail.

Comment: @djangofan I have updated the question with code and exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out this line in your code:

```
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, pf);
```

Instead of specifying the profile you want to use on your grid, just configure the profile in the grid configuration explicitly, or don't specify profile at all so that Firefox just uses a default profile.

If you look at the release notes for Selenium 2.41.0 ( https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG )  you will notice that Firefox 26 is no longer supported.  It was supported in 2.39 but you can use the release notes to make sure you are using the right version.  In fact, Selenium 2.44.0 only supports Firefox 24, 31, 32 and 33.

Comment: it helped me! solved my issue! but why?? IS this a selenium bug? it used to work just fine, not sure why setting Profile does not work any more

Answer (score 0):

I would try downgrading your version of Firefox